# Content security policy not working

Tags: http, browser, http-headers, content-security-policy

I am adding to my response header this header:

`x-content-security-policy default-src 'none';`

I would expect no css or images to be loaded on the page, but everything is loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which browser? Different browser versions understand different header names. 

There's a `:` missing between the header name and it's value.

Comment: Let's see the debug content from your browser!  Headers at least would be useful

Answer (score 4):

For Chrome and newer (v. 23 and newer) versions of Firefox:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
```

For Safari:

```
X-Webkit-CSP: default-src 'none'
```

For older versions of Firefox (v. 23 and older):

```
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
```

Sorry - with IE, only the `sandbox` policy is recognized, and that only in IE 10 and newer.

Comment: I tried with res.setHeader("X-Content-Security-Policy", "sandbox 'allow-same-origin'"); for IE11. Its allowing all other domain external scripts. Any thing I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using firefox, and it is working for me.
This is the header I'm adding in response:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
```

Try to remove "x-", and try with other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

CSP headers now come in at least three flavours and support is very different among browser versions. I'd recommend using just the most standard one (Content-Security-Policy), initially in the report-only mode (Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy#Status for details. You can also try a "iterative" approach to building your content security policy using http://cspbuilder.info/

Comment: Yes, it's been discontinued since but is available as an open-source project https://github.com/kravietz/cspbuilder

Answer (score 0):

You might try including `Header set` before using `Content-Security-Policy:` Like this:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy:
```